# Timeilne view schedulerLicenseKey does not exist in type 'CalendarOptions' in fullcalendar.io Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I upgraded typescript to version 4 and i have upgraded the fullcalendar/resource-timeline package from 5.5.0 to 5.11.0 but I keep getting this error message on my timeline. The calendar package works fine but not the timeline view. It does not show up at all.

> Type '{ schedulerLicenseKey: string; initialView: string; locale: string; slotLabelFormat: ({ weekday: "short"; day: "numeric"; month: "numeric"; } | { hour: "numeric"; minute: "numeric"; hour12: false; })[]; views: { ...; }; headerToolbar: { ...; }; resourceAreaHeaderContent: string; resourceAreaWidth: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CalendarOptions'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'schedulerLicenseKey' does not exist in type 'CalendarOptions'.

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
initialView: 'day',
locale: 'en-gb',
slotLabelFormat: [{
  weekday: 'short',
  day: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric'
},
```